# how can i read a static text file in /src/asset/ directory in ionic2 peoject?

Tags: ionic2, assets, cordova-plugin-file

Pls,pay attention to,the text file isn't in a www website(if it is in a web site ,I can use http request to get it ). 
I want to emphasize the store place of the file:before we run the "ionic cordova build android" the file is just under the directory of "src/asset/". just like the image below:
[in ionic project,and I have a.txt in the directory of "src/asset/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ozDy.png)

after I run the command "ionic cordova build android ",and I get a android APK install file and the app run ok.I want to know,how do I can read a.txt in the app?I know the file is just in the apk,and I cann't get it.

Comment: by the way,I use ionic2,anyone who can use the cordova-plugin-file or http to solve the problem ,pls tell me as soon as possible,I really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this:
Put this piece of code from where you want to access your file in your app.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

this.http.get('assets/TempJobList.json')

.subscribe(res => {

  resolve(res.json());

}, res => {

  reject(res.json());

 });

});
```

In your case "TempJobList.json" is the name of your text file.

Comment: ,but my file isn't a json file,it is a common txt file,how can I get the content of the file?

Comment: use res.text() instead of res.json() to get the content of the file.

Comment: whether I should change the parameter of " assets/TempJobList.json " to cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'assets//TempJobList.json'? @Vibha Pandey

Comment: is that file present in your aaplication directory ? or it is present in src/assets folder?

Comment: just click the link in my question,the file(a.txt) is placed in the /src/assets directory(the directory is belong to the real project directory ,as the image showing,the assets directory  is a node of the actual project directory) @Vibha Pandey

Comment: from my knowledge,I know that after I run " ionic cordova build android " the file(a.txt) mayby stored in the cordova.file.applicationDirectory+'assets directory after the apk is installed. may be I'm wrong. @Vibha Pandey

Comment: I want to emphasize that the file is stored in the apk,and I want to read it after the apk file is installed and the app is running. @Vibha Pandey

Comment: only change the name of the file. Keep other things as it is. It will work